# Automattic's eCommerce Plugin

Tags: plugins, e-commerce

### Question

Does anyone know what plugin Automattic uses for their eCommerce functionality in the MU installation of WordPress located on the free sub-domains at wordpress.com?

Please share where it is available, or if it even is available. I suspect that it might be proprietary, but if not, I like to try and follow Automattics lead when developing my own WP sites to ensure better long-term stability.

---

### More Plugin Details

If you have a wordpress.com account, you'll find the admin panel for the plugin here: `{YOUR_USER_NAME}.wordpress.com/wp-admin/paid-upgrades.php`. These two related resources are pulled from the wordpress.com source code:

1. [/wp-admin/css/store-bundles.css](https://s-ssl.wordpress.com/wp-admin/css/store-bundles.css)
2. [/wp-content/admin-plugins/wpcom-billing/images/WPCOM-Billing-Paypal-Direct.png](https://s-ssl.wordpress.com/wp-content/admin-plugins/wpcom-billing/images/WPCOM-Billing-Paypal-Direct.png)

There are also multiple references to the plugin in [this .pot file](https://wpcom-i18n.svn.automattic.com/wpcom.pot)... open the link in your browser and do an on-page find for: `wpcom-billing`.

Based on the above evidence, it appears that this eCommerce plugin resides in a directory called: **wp-content/admin-plugins/wpcom-billing**, but I'm also wondering if this could just be a modified version of the wp-ecommerce plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to Dion Hulse of Automattic](https://twitter.com/dd32/status/255425625278513152):

> 100% custom, most ecommerce plugins of the time (many years ago) were not suitable for the use, its not opensource either

Comment: Appreciate the detective work... maybe they will open source it one day, but I know how expensive e-commerce development can be and wouldn't blame the Automattic if they considered it part of their competitive advantage.